# Displaying Search Results in the same page in PHP & MySQL using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make Search using PHP and MySQL. I'm using a basic form technique for submitting the data.

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-field">
      <label for="search-field">Search</label>
      <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Enter your search term..." results="5">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Then, I'm passing it through a function inside 'search.php'. Then for the algorithm, it's a simple MySQL statement.

```
$query =("
  SELECT *
  FROM details
  WHERE (`subjects` LIKE '%".$term."%')
  OR (`name` LIKE '%".$term."%')
");
```

However, I wish to display the contents in the same page without any form . I'd like to implement JQuery/an AJAX Method. 
My Function is implemented in a class, and it is:

```
public function search($search_term) {

$term = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($search_term);
$query =("
  SELECT *
  FROM details
  WHERE (`subjects` LIKE '%".$term."%')
  OR (`name` LIKE '%".$term."%')
");
$r=  $this->mysqli->query($query);
if (!$r) {
    echo"<br/>";
die('Invalid query');}
```

I can provide more of my code if my question is lackluster.

Comment: Unrelated to your current issue by `mysql_error` doesn't work with `mysqli`. Are you asking how to use AJAX? If so I'd recommend starting here, https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/.

Comment: Fixed the outdated mysql_error. 
I'd like to know how to implement AJAX to get search results on the same first page(index.php)

Comment: Look at the linked page, make the submit button send an ajax request and disable its default action. Then update the DOM with the returned results, look at the linked page for starting points. This is too broad as is.